# Data from firebase not showing up onclick recyclerview

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have a recycler list view and when one is clicked I'd like to open a new page with its info. When I try to display the job name, location and job charge in the new page, it shows up. However, when I'm trying to display job_date. My app crashes. I don't know why since I'm following the same method to display data. When I comment out wherever job_date occurs, it works normally.

**EDIT**: I'd like to clarify by crash I mean it doesn't close immediately. It works till I get to the listview page and then it just suddenly goes back to my main activity page which just has a button to proceed to the next page.

I only get these two **errors** in my logcat but I'm not sure if it has anything to do with the problem:

```
03-14 14:11:06.634 3417-3423/? E/art: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe

03-14 14:11:07.165 3417-3417/? E/HAL: load: id=gralloc != hmi->id=gralloc
```

I have a Firebase database as follows:

[image]

This is my main **Home class**:

```
package com.example.oddsynew;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Home extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseReference myRef;
    RecyclerView newJobList;
    ArrayList<Job> list;
    HomeAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        newJobList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.newJobs);
        newJobList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        list = new ArrayList<Job>();

        adapter = new HomeAdapter(Home.this, list);
        newJobList.setAdapter(adapter);



        myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Jobs");
        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    String jobkey = ds.getKey();
                    Job j = ds.getValue(Job.class);
                    list.add(j);
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(Home.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is my **job info class**

```
package com.example.oddsynew;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class JobInfo extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView jobName, jobCharge, jobLocation, jobDate;
    ImageView profPic;
    String jobname, jobloc, jobcharge, profpic, jobdate;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_job_info);

        jobName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.jobName_info);
        jobCharge = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.jobCharge_info);
        jobLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.jobLocation_info);
        profPic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.prof_pic_info);
        //jobDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.jobDate_info);

        jobname = getIntent().getStringExtra("jobName");
        jobloc = getIntent().getStringExtra("jobLocation");
        jobcharge = getIntent().getStringExtra("jobCharge");
        profpic = getIntent().getStringExtra("profPic");
        //jobdate = getIntent().getStringExtra("jobDate");

        jobName.setText(jobname);
        jobCharge.setText(jobcharge);
        jobLocation.setText(jobloc);
        //jobDate.setText(jobdate);

        Picasso.get().load(profpic).into(profPic);


    }
}
```

Followed by my **adapter class**:

```
    package com.example.oddsynew;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class HomeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<Job> jobs;

    public HomeAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Job> j){
        context = c;
        jobs = j;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.job_row, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.recruiterName.setText(jobs.get(position).getRecruiter_name());
        holder.jobName.setText(jobs.get(position).getJob_name());
        holder.jobLocation.setText(jobs.get(position).getLocation());
        holder.jobCharge.setText(jobs.get(position).getJob_charge());
        holder.jobDate.setText(jobs.get(position).getJob_date());
        Picasso.get().load(jobs.get(position).getProf_pic()).into(holder.profPic);

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, JobInfo.class);
                intent.putExtra("recruiterName",jobs.get(position).getRecruiter_name());
                intent.putExtra("jobName",jobs.get(position).getJob_name());
                intent.putExtra("jobCharge",jobs.get(position).getJob_charge());
                intent.putExtra("jobLocation",jobs.get(position).getLocation());
                intent.putExtra("profPic",jobs.get(position).getProf_pic());
                //intent.putExtra("jobDate",jobs.get(position).getJob_date());
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return jobs.size();
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView recruiterName, jobName, jobLocation, jobCharge, jobDate;
        ImageView profPic;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            recruiterName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recruiterName);
            jobName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.jobName);
            jobLocation = itemView.findViewById(R.id.jobLocation);
            jobCharge = itemView.findViewById(R.id.jobCharge);
            profPic = itemView.findViewById(R.id.prof_pic);
            //jobDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.jobDate_info);
        }
    }

}
```

And here is my **model**:

```
   package com.example.oddsynew;

public class Job {
    private String job_name, recruiter_name, location, job_charge, add_pref, job_date, start_time, end_time, tasks, job_desc, prof_pic;

    public Job() {
    }

    public Job(String job_name, String recruiter_name, String location, String job_charge, String add_pref, String job_date, String start_time, String end_time, String tasks, String job_desc, String prof_pic) {
        this.job_name = job_name;
        this.recruiter_name = recruiter_name;
        this.location = location;
        this.job_charge = job_charge;
        this.add_pref = add_pref;
        this.job_date = job_date;
        this.start_time = start_time;
        this.end_time = end_time;
        this.tasks = tasks;
        this.job_desc = job_desc;
        this.prof_pic = prof_pic;
    }

    public Job(String prof_pic) {
        this.prof_pic = prof_pic;
    }

    public String getJob_name() {
        return job_name;
    }

    public void setJob_name(String job_name) {
        this.job_name = job_name;
    }

    public String getRecruiter_name() {
        return recruiter_name;
    }

    public void setRecruiter_name(String recruiter_name) {
        this.recruiter_name = recruiter_name;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public String getJob_charge() {
        return job_charge;
    }

    public void setJob_charge(String job_charge) {
        this.job_charge = job_charge;
    }

    public String getProf_pic() {
        return prof_pic;
    }

    public void setProf_pic(String prof_pic) {
        this.prof_pic = prof_pic;
    }

    public String getAdd_pref() {
        return add_pref;
    }

    public void setAdd_pref(String add_pref) {
        this.add_pref = add_pref;
    }

    public String getJob_date() {
        return job_date;
    }

    public void setJob_date(String job_date) {
        this.job_date = job_date;
    }

    public String getStart_time() {
        return start_time;
    }

    public void setStart_time(String start_time) {
        this.start_time = start_time;
    }

    public String getEnd_time() {
        return end_time;
    }

    public void setEnd_time(String end_time) {
        this.end_time = end_time;
    }

    public String getTasks() {
        return tasks;
    }

    public void setTasks(String tasks) {
        this.tasks = tasks;
    }

    public String getJob_desc() {
        return job_desc;
    }

    public void setJob_desc(String job_desc) {
        this.job_desc = job_desc;
    }
}
```

My **Job Info UI**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Home"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        style="@style/HeaderStyle"
        android:layout_width="252dp"
        android:layout_height="39dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
        android:text="Find Your Next Gig"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageButton"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="80dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
        android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
        android:paddingLeft="-10dp"
        android:queryBackground="@android:color/transparent"
        android:queryHint="Search Jobs"
        android:searchIcon="@drawable/ic_magnifying_glass"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:theme="@style/Search" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
        android:background="@null"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_burger_button" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
        android:background="@null"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/search"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_noun_filter" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="358dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="#fff"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/search">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/prof_pic_info"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.015" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/jobName_info"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/prof_pic_info"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/jobLocation_info"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_light"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/prof_pic_info"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/jobName_info" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/jobCharge_info"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_light"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/jobLocation_info"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/jobName_info" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/jobDate_info"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/prof_pic_info"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/jobCharge_info" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/jobTime_info"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/prof_pic_info"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/jobDate_info" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/jobDesc_header"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/prof_pic_info" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/jobTasks_header"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/jobDesc" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/additonalPref_header"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/jobTasks" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/jobTasks"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/jobTasks_header" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/additionalPref"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/additonalPref_header" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/jobDesc"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/jobDesc_header" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**EDIT:** As you can see here, it works when I retrieve this info, but when I try to retrieve job_date the same way. It crashes.

[image]

**EDIT:** For reference, this is my recycler list view:

[image]

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: @AlexMamo I have mentioned the error I got in my post.

Comment: Can you share error log please and how do you save this job object to the real time database ? I think most important part is both of them.

Comment: Pl share complete error log, the one you mentioned is not enough

Comment: Does your job_row layout file have the same field names as in the activity_job_info layout file?

Comment: @RajenRaiyarela no they're different

Comment: @Devika.S, In that case, pl check the id fields. As I see jobDate_info is present in the activity layout but is it present in the recyclerview layout as well?

Comment: @RajenRaiyarela What do you mean? I already have a working recycler view. My problem is when a person clicks on a recycler view item, it must show more details. Which also works to an extent. But I'm only able to retrieve the job name, location, and job charge. For some reason when I try to retrieve job_date. It crashes like I mentioned above.The job info page is just a normal page, not a recycler view

Comment: @Devika.S In your code, everything looks good and i cannot figure out the crash condition. Just one thing I see which needs change, instead of position use getAdapterPosition() inside click listener. Also, pl use try catch, so an exception will be caught and the screen will not change. Both inside clicklistener and in oncreate inside activity.

Comment: @RajenRaiyarela I have tried what you asked but the problem still remains. Are you sure everything is fine? I cannot figure out what's wrong either. Question, do I have to initialize holder again in job_info class or something? I'm not able to move ahead because of this problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209621/discussion-between-rajen-raiyarela-and-devika-s).

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the problem, all I had to do was remove holder for job_date. And it worked for some reason. Thanks to those who tried to help anyway.

```
package com.example.oddsynew;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class HomeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<Job> jobs;

    public HomeAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Job> j){
        context = c;
        jobs = j;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.job_row, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.recruiterName.setText(jobs.get(position).getRecruiter_name());
        holder.jobName.setText(jobs.get(position).getJob_name());
        holder.jobLocation.setText(jobs.get(position).getLocation());
        holder.jobCharge.setText(jobs.get(position).getJob_charge());
        //holder.jobDate.setText(jobs.get(position).getJob_date()); //Removed this 
        statement
        Picasso.get().load(jobs.get(position).getProf_pic()).into(holder.profPic);

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try{
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, JobInfo.class);
                intent.putExtra("recruiterName",jobs.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getRecruiter_name());
                intent.putExtra("jobName",jobs.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getJob_name());
                intent.putExtra("jobCharge",jobs.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getJob_charge());
                intent.putExtra("jobLocation",jobs.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getLocation());
                intent.putExtra("profPic",jobs.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getProf_pic());
                intent.putExtra("jobDate",jobs.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getJob_date());

               context.startActivity(intent);
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return jobs.size();
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView recruiterName, jobName, jobLocation, jobCharge, jobDate;
        ImageView profPic;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            recruiterName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recruiterName);
            jobName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.jobName);
            jobLocation = itemView.findViewById(R.id.jobLocation);
            jobCharge = itemView.findViewById(R.id.jobCharge);
            profPic = itemView.findViewById(R.id.prof_pic);
        }
    }

}
```